# CaseInsensitiveSearch in swift5?

Tags: swift

```
tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
```

I want to use the above code in swift5
But can't use

```
tmp.range (of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
```

I changed it as above, but is the same code correct?

Thanks for reading

Comment: Did you try it? Does it compile? Does it work as expected?

Comment: "But can't use" Why ? Is there an error? A compiler error? A crash? What does it says? What did say the autcompletion?  Because `let range = "Hello".range(of: "hello", options: .caseInsensitive)` seems to work on my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```
let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated [`localizedStandardContains(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/localizedstandardcontains(_:)) function for this purpose :

> This is the most appropriate method for doing user-level string searches, similar to how searches are done generally in the system. **The search is locale-aware, case and diacritic insensitive.** The exact list of search options applied may change over time.

Usage :

```
"fÔo bàr".localizedStandardContains("foo bar") // true
```